# DIY cable railing corner post configuration?

Tags: deck, stairs, cables, railing

Using [Steeltek](http://www.steel-tek.com/) pipe fittings to create a corner railing over a half lower level. My plan was to have the uprights and top & bottom rails made from the galvanized pipe & fittings and use cable rail for the in between horizontal rails.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to run the cable *through* the corner post so I can use the two outside posts as terminals. My concern is that I want to alleviate any kinking/scraping of the cable as it makes that turn and is tensioned.

My little drawing:

```
 .--.                       .--. 
/    \_____________________/__  \
\    /                     \  | /
 '--'                       '-|'
                              |
                              |
                              |
                              |
                            .--. 
                           /    \
                           \    /
                            '--'
```

Comment: Probably either "only run straight cables" (don't use one cable and bend it, use two shorter cables) or just deburr the holes well. Perhaps use a bushing in each hole. If wanting to be crazy-fussy, put a smaller rod or pipe inside the corner pipe to act as a crude bearing. Or go ask how it's done on sailboats at a boatyard or boat forum...

Comment: Even though it is listed as a comment, Ecnerwal has the answer... The coaxial pipe is a great idea...

Comment: The SteelTek web site is showing the sizes of their fittings as 3/4" and 1 1/4" sizes. I do not think I would ever want to even begin to build deck rails out of pipe that was smaller than about 2".

Comment: The SteelTek pipe page also has these warning statements. Pipe made to fit with SteelTek fittings. Not for Scafolding Applications. This product contains chemicals including lead known to the State of California to cause cancer ad birth defects or other reproductive harm. Wash hand after use.